# How can I present a native UIViewController in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I'm trying to use mpandroidchart's iOS version package in RN native IOS, This is how I tried to implement it.

ChartManager.m

```
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNTChartManager, RCTViewManager)

@end
```

ChartManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import React

@objc(RNTChartManager)
class RNTChartManager: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    let barChart = BarChartViewController()
    return barChart
  }
}
```

ChartViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Charts
import React

class BarChartViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
    }

}
```

AppName-Bridging-Header.h

```
#ifndef Investor_Bridging_Header_h
#define Investor_Bridging_Header_h
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"
#import "React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h"

#endif
```

How would I do this in React Native? I can't write a bridged UI component since it's a UIViewController, not a UIView.
I know this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you going to implement UIVIewController?

Comment: To display a chart using mpandroid chart. I have no prior knowledge in IOS and I have only found this approach. Is there any other way to acheive this @DevLover

Comment: There are so many react-native chart components like below.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-charts
https://www.fusioncharts.com/react-native-charts

Comment: Thanks, but this is the best package suits for my need, I have checked all these packages before @DevLover